# Is there a name for this type of matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am preparing to publish an academic article on computational efficiency and image processing.  In my work, I have come across what I can best describe as a non-square skew (symmetric or repeating) matrix (I know it can't be symmetric since it's non-square).

Here are some examples of what it may look like:

(9 x 2)

\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -6  \\
0 & -6  \\
0 & -6  \\
3 & -3  \\
3 & -3  \\
3 & -3  \\
6 & 0   \\
6 & 0   \\
6 & 0 \end{array}

(16 x 3)

\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -12 & -24  \\
0 & -12 & -24  \\
0 & -12 & -24  \\
0 & -12 & -24  \\
8 & -4 & -16  \\
8 & -4 & -16  \\
8 & -4 & -16  \\
8 & -4 & -16  \\
16 & 4 & -8  \\
16 & 4 & -8  \\
16 & 4 & -8  \\
16 & 4 & -8  \\
24 & 12 & 0  \\
24 & 12 & 0  \\
24 & 12 & 0  \\
24 & 12 & 0 \end{array}

(4 x 6)

\begin{array}{cccccc}
0 & -2 & -4 & -6 & -8 & -10  \\
0 & -2 & -4 & -6 & -8 & -10 \\
10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
10 & 8 & 6 & 4 & 2 & 0 \end{array}

Is there a specific name for this type of matrix?  If so, I could not find one.

Also,  what are some properties of this matrix that I may be overlooking?

1) It seems that the rank will always be 2.

2) (If the matrix is A): AA' and A'A is always symmetric.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just a note: 2) is true for all matrices.

Comment: It seems like you could describe your matrices using block matrix notation. That could help you ...

Comment: What you could do is write it as a [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product): 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -6  \\
0 & -6  \\
0 & -6  \\
3 & -3  \\
3 & -3  \\
3 & -3  \\
6 & 0   \\
6 & 0   \\
6 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=
3\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -2  \\
1 & -1  \\
2 & -0 \end{pmatrix}\otimes
\begin{pmatrix}
1  \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$ and maybe use something like [Toeplitz matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix)...

Comment: It looks like the rows and columns are all arithmetic progressions. Using the representation draks has mentioned above, I think your matrices might be of the form $r A \otimes b$, where $A$ is an $(m+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix with $A_{ij} = ni-mj$ and $b$ is an $r \times 1$ matrix with all $1$s. Noticing that it has such a simple structure, you should be able to get a lot of information about it. For example, you can prove your claim that it's rank is always 2.